# Discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hello')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**I am creating a Discord command handler using discord.js version 14.4.0 but I keep getting this error, here is my code:**

```js
const settings = require(`${process.cwd()}/config/settings.json`);
const ee = require(`${process.cwd()}/config/embed.json`);

const colors = require("colors");

const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "hello",
  description: "say hello!",
  cooldown: settings.cooldown,
  memberpermissions: [],
  requiredroles: [],
  alloweduserids: [],
  type: Discord.ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  options: [],
  run: async (client, interaction) => {
      try {
        interaction.reply({ content: `${client.word.hello}` });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(colors.red(error));
        let somethingWrong = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(ee.colors.Red)
        .setTitle("❌| Something wrong!")
        .setDescription(`❌| Sorry, I failed setting up...!`)
        .setFooter({ text: `${interaction.guild.name}`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL() })
        return interaction.reply({ embeds: [somethingWrong], ephemeral: true });
      }
  }
};
```

The error I get when running that command:

```js
interaction.reply({ content: `${client.word.hello}` });
```

and this my index.js file:

```js
const lang_db = require("./dataBases/db");

const dotenv = require("dotenv"); dotenv.config();
const colors = require("colors");
const fs = require("fs");

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [32767],
  partials: [
    Discord.Partials.GuildScheduledEvent,
    Discord.Partials.ThreadMember,
    Discord.Partials.GuildMember,
    Discord.Partials.Reaction,
    Discord.Partials.Channel,
    Discord.Partials.Message,
    Discord.Partials.User,
  ],
});

client.slashCommands = new Discord.Collection();
module.exports = client;

fs.readdirSync("./handlers").forEach((handler) => {
  require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  let lang = await lang_db.get(`language_${interaction.guild.id}`);
  if(lang == null) {
    lang = "en";
  } else if(lang == "ar") {
    lang = "ar"
  }
  let word = require(`./languages/${lang}.json`);
  client.word = word;
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN).catch((error) => {
  console.log(colors.red(error));
});
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hello')

handlers/slashCommand.js

```js
const colors = require("colors");
const fs = require("fs");

const AsciiTable = require("ascii-table");
const table = new AsciiTable().setHeading("Slash Commands", "Stats").setBorder("|", "=", "0", "0");

const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const APPLICATION_ID = process.env.APPLICATION_ID;
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const rest = new REST({ version: "10" }).setToken(TOKEN);

module.exports = (client) => {
  const slashCommands = [];
  fs.readdirSync("./slashCommands/").forEach(async (dir) => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(`./slashCommands/${dir}/`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
    for (const file of files) {
      const slashCommand = require(`../slashCommands/${dir}/${file}`);
      slashCommands.push({
        name: slashCommand.name,
        description: slashCommand.description,
        type: slashCommand.type,
        options: slashCommand.options ? slashCommand.options : null,
        default_permission: slashCommand.default_permission ? slashCommand.default_permission : null,
        default_member_permissions: slashCommand.default_member_permissions ? Discord.PermissionsBitField.resolve(slashCommand.default_member_permissions).toString() : null,
      });
      if (slashCommand.name) {
        client.slashCommands.set(slashCommand.name, slashCommand);
        table.addRow(file.split(".js")[0], "✅");
      } else {
        table.addRow(file.split(".js")[0], "⛔");
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(colors.green(table.toString()));
  (async () => {
    try {
      const data = await rest.put(process.env.GUILD_ID ? Routes.applicationGuildCommands(APPLICATION_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID) : Routes.applicationCommands(APPLICATION_ID), { body: slashCommands });
      console.log(colors.green(`Started refreshing ${slashCommands.length} application (/) commands.`));
      console.log(colors.green(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(colors.red(error));
    }
  })();
};
```

events/guid/interactionCreate.js

```js
const ee = require(`${process.cwd()}/config/embed.json`);

const colors = require("colors");
const ms = require("ms");

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = require("../..");
const delay = new Discord.Collection();

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  const slashCommand = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
  if (interaction.type == 4) {
    if (slashCommand.autocomplete) {
      const choices = [];
      await slashCommand.autocomplete(interaction, choices);
    }
  }
  if (!interaction.type == 2) return;
  if (!slashCommand)
  return client.slashCommands.delete(interaction.commandName);
  try {
    if (slashCommand.cooldown) {
      if (delay.has(`${slashCommand.name}-${interaction.user.id}`)) {
        let time = ms(delay.get(`${slashCommand.name}-${interaction.user.id}`) - Date.now(), { long: true }).includes("ms") ? "0 second" : ms(delay.get(`${slashCommand.name}-${interaction.user.id}`) - Date.now(), { long: true });
        let timeLeft = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(ee.colors.Red)
        .setTitle("❌| You are not allowed to run this command!")
        .setDescription(`❌| Please wait **${time}** before reusing the \`${slashCommand.name}\` command!`)
        .setFooter({ text: `${interaction.guild.name}`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL() })
        return interaction.reply({ embeds: [timeLeft], ephemeral: true });
      }
    }

    if (slashCommand.memberpermissions && slashCommand.memberpermissions.length > 0 && !interaction.member.permissions.has(slashCommand.memberpermissions)) {
      let memberPerms = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(ee.colors.Red)
      .setTitle("❌| You are not allowed to run this command!")
      .setDescription(`❌| You need these Permission(s): \`${slashCommand.memberpermissions}\``)
      .setFooter({ text: `${interaction.guild.name}`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL() })
      return interaction.reply({ embeds: [memberPerms], ephemeral: true });
    }

    if (slashCommand.requiredroles && slashCommand.requiredroles.length > 0 && interaction.member.roles.cache.size > 0 && !interaction.member.roles.cache.some(r => slashCommand.requiredroles.includes(r.id))) {
      let rolesPerms = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(ee.colors.Red)
      .setTitle("❌| You are not allowed to run this command!")
      .setDescription(`❌| You need to have one of the Following Roles: <@&${slashCommand.requiredroles}>`)
      .setFooter({ text: `${interaction.guild.name}`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL() })
      return interaction.reply({ embeds: [rolesPerms], ephemeral: true });
    }

    if (slashCommand.alloweduserids && slashCommand.alloweduserids.length > 0 && !slashCommand.alloweduserids.includes(interaction.member.id)) {
      let userPerms = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(ee.colors.Red)
      .setTitle("❌| You are not allowed to run this command!")
      .setDescription(`❌| You need to be one of the Following Users: <@!${slashCommand.alloweduserids}>`)
      .setFooter({ text: `${interaction.guild.name}`, iconURL: interaction.guild.iconURL() })
      return interaction.reply({ embeds: [userPerms], ephemeral: true });
    }

    await slashCommand.run(client, interaction);
    delay.set(`${slashCommand.name}-${interaction.user.id}`, Date.now() + slashCommand.cooldown * 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      delay.delete(`${slashCommand.name}-${interaction.user.id}`);
    }, slashCommand.cooldown * 1000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(colors.red(error));
  }
});
```

I don't know why this is happening, please could someone help me?

Comment: Can you show your command handler file as well?

Comment: @Caladan I don't think the problem is from there

Comment: `client.word` is `undefined`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Do you know how to fix it please

Comment: The error might have come because of the improper order of arguments passed in to the `run()` function. It's a problem seen a lot here which is why I asked you to show the command handler file

Comment: @Caladan

this file "slashCommand.js" from folder "hadnlers" :
 - `https://pastebin.com/7ZenbWGt` ===> Password: **slashCommand.js**

this file "interactionCreate.js" from folder "events/guild" :
- `https://pastebin.com/yjnahLyn` ===> Password: **interactionCreate.js**

Comment: Can you add the code directly in the question, as the pastebin link is not working for me

Comment: @Caladan Ok...Done!!

Comment: It's possible that since you're setting `client.word` in a different function than the function in which the command is called, by the time the command runs, `client.word` has still not been set yet. Can you try putting the part where you set `client.word` into `events/guild/interactionCreate.js`? If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what the problem could be

Comment: @Caladan Thanks man, I didn't think of it this way, it was a stupid mistake of me, I fixed it thanks to you, thank you again :)